# SQLite3 и Python3, вызов данных из БД

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Вызываю данные из БД, при вызове вроде

```
c.execute("""
SELECT smth FROM smth
""")
c.fetchone()
```

Я получаю список из одного элемента, а при

```
c.execute("""
SELECT smth FROM smth
""")
c.fetchall()
```

Я получаю кортеж из списков по одному элементу.
 Могу ли я получить просто кортеж из строк, а не списков, внутри которых по строке? могу ли я сразу считывать из БД текст как строки, а числа как числа?

Comment: Не понял проблемы, `fetchone` возвращает то же самое, что и `fetchall()[0]`

Comment: Речь не идёт о проблемах с фетчами, проблема в типовании, можно ли не считывать данные как списки из одного элемента , а сразу верные типы, числа, строки

Comment: А зачем? Если очень хочется, всегда можно сделать `[x[0] for x in c.fetchall()]` и соответственно `c.fetchone()[0]`, а пихать это внутрь sqlite3 смысла мало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с использованием SQL Alchemy:

Сначала создаем SQLite DB:

```
C:\Temp>sqlite3 c:\temp\a.db
SQLite version 3.13.0 2016-05-18 10:57:30
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> create table tab(name varchar(50), val int);
sqlite> insert into tab values ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 2), ('B', 4), ('C', 6);
sqlite> select * from tab;
name        val
----------  ----------
A           1
A           2
A           3
B           2
B           4
C           6
sqlite> .exit
```

Теперь воспользуемся SQLAchemy:

```
In [101]: from sqlalchemy import create_engine

In [102]: engine = create_engine('sqlite:///c:/temp/a.db')

In [103]: conn = engine.connect()

In [104]: conn.execute('select * from tab').fetchall()
Out[104]: [('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 2), ('B', 4), ('C', 6)]
```

Строки и целые (`int`) определились правильно...

Чтобы получить список строк, вместо списка кортежей:

```
In [106]: rows = conn.execute('select name from tab').fetchall()

In [107]: rows
Out[107]: [('A',), ('A',), ('A',), ('B',), ('B',), ('C',)]

In [108]: names = [x[0] for x in rows]

In [109]: names
Out[109]: ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
```

или:

```
In [113]: from operator import itemgetter

In [114]: list(map(itemgetter(0), conn.execute('select name from tab').fetchall()))
Out[114]: ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

Если задача в том, чтобы при извлечении именно одного поля через `fetchall()` в результате получался список значений для этого поля из таблицы.

Можно предложить решение через `row_factory`:

```
import sqlite3

def my_row_factory(cursor, row):
    ''' Функция будет иметь доступ к каждой строке выборки.
        cursor содержит метаданные запроса,
        row содержит данные выборки
    '''

    if len(cursor.description) == 1:
        return row[0]
    else:
        return row    

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

con.row_factory = my_row_factory
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE table USER(id integer primary key, name text)')

cur.execute('INSERT INTO USER(name) values (?)', ('petrushka',))
cur.execute('INSERT INTO USER(name) values (?)', ('barmalei',))
cur.execute('INSERT INTO USER(name) values (?)', ('alien',))
cur.execute('INSERT INTO USER(name) values (?)', ('scally',))
cur.execute('INSERT INTO USER(name) values (?)', ('molder',))
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from USER as a")
print(cur.fetchall())
```

[Описание row_factory в документации](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory)